# Node event emitter in other modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I have 3 different javascript files, the smallest one is emitting an event, meanwhile the second (bigger one) file picks up the event and sends it further to the main file.
 This is what I have tried so far:

```
//mini.js
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var ee = new EventEmitter;

console.log("Emitting event");
var message = "Hello world";
ee.emit('testing',message);


//second.js
var mini = require('./mini.js');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var ee = new EventEmitter;

mini.on('testing',function(message){
    console.log("Second file received a message:",message);

    console.log("Passing further");
    ee.emit('testing',message);
});

//main.js
var sec = require('./second.js');

sec.on('testing',function(message){
    console.log("Main file received the message",message);
});
```

However, I get

```
mini.on('testing',function(message){
        ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

error when executing the file with node.

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work :

This is the content to put inside **first.js** :

```
//first.js
var util = require('util'),
    EventEmitter = require('events');


function First () {
  EventEmitter.call(this)
}
util.inherits(First, EventEmitter);


First.prototype.sendMessage = function (msg) {    
  this.emit('message', {msg:msg});
};


module.exports = First;
```

This is the content to put inside **second.js** :

```
//second.js
var First = require('./first.js');
var firstEvents = new First();

// listen for the 'message event from first.js'
firstEvents.on('message',function(data){
    console.log('recieved data from first.js is : ',data);
});


// to emit message from inside first.js
firstEvents.sendMessage('first message from first.js');
```

**Now run** `node second.js` and you should have the 'message' event fired for you.

You can use this pattern to achieve any level of messaging between modules.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @NedasMikoleika in this case rename **second.js** to **main.js** and that's it or there is something i'm missing here ?

Comment: I actually have everything else (the rest of my server) in the **main.js** file.

Comment: @NedasMikoleika no problem, just add the content of **second.js** to your **main.js** file.

Answer (score 3):

You're not exporting your `EventEmitter` instance in mini.js. Add this to mini.js:

```
module.exports = ee;
```

You'll also need to add a similar line in second.js if you want to export its `EventEmitter` instance in order to make it available to main.js.

Another problem you'll run into is that you're emitting `testing` in mini.js before second.js adds its `testing` event handler, so it will end up missing that event.

Comment: Any possible fixes for this?